# Standard error of the mean of several values of y predicted from a multiple regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, standard-error, prediction-interval

I have a multiple regression equation that predicts a trait of interest ($y$) from two measured traits ($x_1$  and $x_2$). I want to measure $x_1$ and $x_2$ for $k$ individuals of a certain plant species, and use this regression to estimate the mean and standard error of $y$ for this species. I know the standard error of the predicted $y$ value for one new observation is:

$$
s.e.(\hat{y_o}) =\sqrt {MSE  (1 + x^T_o(X^TX)^{-1}x_o}\
$$

but what is the standard error for a mean of $k$ new observations? It doesn't like I'm accounting for the error from the regression if I just take the standard error of the $\hat{y_o}$s as if they were any other set of numbers.

Thanks for any help.